# Put the numbers $\cos a=a; \sin \cos b=b; \cos \sin c=c$ in ascending order

Tags: trigonometry

> Let $a,b,c \in \left[0;\frac{\pi}2\right]$ such that 
>   $$\cos a=a; \sin \cos b=b; \cos \sin c=c.$$
>   Put the numbers $a, b, c$ in ascending order.

**My work so far:**

If $x>0$, than $\sin x<x$.

If $x \in \left[0;\frac{\pi}2\right]$ then $\cos x$ decreasing function.

Then $$\sin \cos x<\cos x< \cos \sin x.$$
$$b=\sin \cos b<\cos b;$$
$$\cos c<\cos \sin c=c.$$

*I need help here.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Note that $x$ is strictly increasing and $\cos x$ is strictly decreasing (in the range $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$). So $x<\cos x$ iff $x<a$.

(2) We have $\sin x<x$ (for all $x$ in the range $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$), so $\sin c<c$. But $\cos x$ is strictly decreasing, so $c=\cos\sin c>\cos c$. Hence applying (1) we have $c>a$.

(3) $\sin x<x$ also implies $b=\sin\cos b<\cos b$. So, again applying (1), we have $b<a$.

Summarising $b<a<c$.